# .Q.trp and bt handling

Tags: kdb, k

I saw (in `.Q.fpn`) the following technique to parse and show the `bt` object passed to `.Q.trp` function:

```
q)f:{x+1}
q).Q.trp[f;`a;{'(x;y)}]
'type
  [4]  f:{x+1}
           ^
  [3]  (.Q.trp)

  [2]  .Q.trp[f;`a;{'(x;y)}]
       ^
  [0]  .Q.trp[f;`a;{'(x;y)}]
       ^
```

`'(x;y)` seems like an exception building construction, - but Kx documentation says that there are only two ways of exception building: from symbol and from string. It is looks like we can built an exception from a list of `(symbol; bt object)`.

So what the construction `'(x;y)` stands for?

Can we build something different than exception with `'(x;y)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that this is a specific signal recently allowed along with the addition of the .Q.trp/.Q.bt functionality. It looks like it works only for `(symbol;bt object)` or `(string;bt object)`, anything else is unrecognized.

```
q).Q.trp[{1+x};`a;{'(x;y;1)}]
'stype
```

The output can be stored if returned without the signal:

```
q)r:.Q.trp[{1+x};`a;{(x;y)}]
```

and this type of signal seems to work in any context, not just within .Q.trp:

```
q)'("other";last r)
'other
  [2]  {1+x}
         ^
  [1]  (.Q.trp)

  [0]  r:.Q.trp[{1+x};`a;{(x;y)}]
```

I suspect the `last r` has a very specific format/shape that one could fabricate but it seems like an unnecessary use-case.

Bonus oddities:

This works:

```
q)'("other";())
'other
  [0]  '("other";())
        ^
```

but other things I've tried show up weird errors:

```
q)'("other";(();()))
pl0
pl0
q)
q)'("other";"abc")
srr
```

Comment: that `srr` error is an odd one. There was a question a few months back with that error and I assumed it was a typo for `ssr` or an undefined variable